# Bittorrent protocol not used by uTorrent client

Tags: networking, bittorrent, wireshark

I created a virtual environment for torrent download which included 4 virtual machines. Of the four, three machines acts as  peers and the other acts as a tracker. Using `uTorrent` I created a torrent file from one of the peers and announced it to the tracker. From another peer I tried downloading the file using the torrent file created and it worked. However when I captured the network packets during the download using wireshark, I was surprised to see that the Bittorrent protocol was not at all used for the piece transfer. Neither it had any `request` or `have` messages. UDP is used for the transfer.

Why is it so? How can I instruct the client to use Bittorrent protocol for transfer?

Comment: I think reading about the about the OSI model would help here - UDP is layer 4 , bitorrent is layer 7. The TCP/IP model is more in fashion now - I'd consider UDP a transport, and bitorrent a application protocol. Its also worth considering bitorrent and some other clients use a different protocol as well, called µTP

Comment: @JourneymanGeek : Ya.. I went through Micro transport protocol also. But I need to study the messages passed between the peer and client using bittorrent protocol.

Comment: So do you mean udp or µTP ?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: UDP

Comment: hmm. Do you have protocol encryption turned on?

Comment: Oh yes...turning of uTP transport solved it..thank you

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: but here I am adding the peers manually by clicking add peer...should I configure something to make the tracker find it?

Comment: Posted that as an answer. You should have the tracker added into your torrent to start with, and dht should be available.

Comment: While creating torrent I am adding `http://tracker IP:port/announce` to the tracker field...isn't it enough..

Comment: @JourneymanGeek:DHT is checked in the tracker.. In all the peers it is unchecked..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off µTP (Its a different application layer, and useless for your needs) and completely disable protocol encryption.

Comment: Thnk u... while using this protocol is there some way by which I can identify which pieces are received??(as piece index is mentioned in the peer messages of bittorrent protocol)

Comment: No idea. I *use* bittorrent for all my linux installer downloading needs, but I don't have that much of a clue about the underlying protocol

Answer (score 0):

What you have is the bittorrent protocol, kindasorta.

What you're seeing there is called the [utorrent transfer protocol](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0029.html) (uTP) which was introduced in late 08 to bittorrent inc.'s clients (utorrent and BitTorrent[mainline]) as a way to reduce some traffic usage, and decongest networks a bit.

It's basically a UDP-based version of bittorrent. When it was annouced in 2008, some people lost their marbles, and [claimed that the world would end](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2008/12/01/richard_bennett_utorrent_udp?page=1) and that the major shift to UDP would kill gaming, video conferencing and so on. As you can see, it didn't. The DRM-based trackers (aka 'private trackers') also threw a bit of a wobbly, as the different data quantities threw a wrench into their DRM enforcement systems, and also upset some of their paid-prioritization systems, [so they banned](https://torrentfreak.com/utorrent-accused-of-unfairness-banned-by-trackers-100314/) any client using it. Then again, most of the people behind those sites have no clue what they're doing anyway (I speak from experience)

Comment: Which is funny since as of 2014, quite a few decent clients support it - one of the libtorrents does (rasterbar I think, but not rakshasa, and it does seem rather well behaved on lesser internet connections.

Comment: oh, it's extremely well behaved on most internet connections - that was actually the main reason for its development.